# Bluetooth won't find devices!

Tags: bluetooth

So the other day, I turned-off bluetooth via the system tray to save power... When I connected to mains power again, I was unable to turn bluetooth back on through either the system tray *or* the bluetooth settings, though this was rectified after a restart.

Following this was Ubuntu's refusal to work with *any* of my (previously) paired bluetooth devices... It showed them in the list as before, by simply would *not* connect to them.

In an attempt to rectify this issue, I deleted my bluetooth devices with the intention of pairing them again... But now Ubuntu won't "find" any devices!

As a test, I also made Ubuntu discoverable so that other bluetooth devices can "see" it and interestingly, *none* of my other bluetooth devices can "see" Ubuntu...

I'm not too sure what's going on, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Install `blueman-applet `  and try agin.

Comment: It didn't work: $ sudo install blueman-applet
install: missing destination file operand after ‘blueman-applet’
Try 'install --help' for more information.

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get install blueman-applet `

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already and had errors too: "E: Unable to locate package blueman-applet"

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install blueman`.

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks. By the way, I can't accept your solution as the answer, because you posted it as a comment rather than an actual answer...

Comment: I'm having a similar issue (in that I deleted a device and now can't rediscover it). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling blueman, but that didn't fix the issue. This fixed the issue for you?

Answer (score -2):

In the past I had luck in reloading the bluetooth driver in the repository. Another option is if Bluetooth device is external then reinsert it into another USB port.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're saying here....