# Bluetooth Broadcom BCM20702 does not load firmware (driver issue) - 14.04

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

I am able to establish a connection between a Bluetooth ear-piece and the Bluetooth controller in the PC. The problem is that the O/S does not provide an option to send audio output to the Bluetooth controller - this is a Bluetooth controller firmware issue. Basically I am not able to load the *.hcd file I made from a *.hex file into the kernel (my interpretation of this issue with my very limited understanding).

Image #1 - Bluetooth is connected to Bluetooth card in PC (screen shot is of 'blueman' software as suggested in [Bluetooth won't find devices!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424454/bluetooth-wont-find-devices)):
[image]

Image #2 - Core of problem, no option to output sound to connected Bluetooth device:
[image]

Image #3 - when I run `dmesg | grep -i blue` the result is as follows (confirms the issue is a firmware problem):

[image: firmware issue image]

I have spent over 8 hours looking through posts on this issue, and I can say
that out of very many posts with similar unanswered issues, there is a gem which explains how to fix this issue. Have a look: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu/632348#632348)
I followed this instruction manual to the T! The only problem is that it didn't work for me. The image below shows the final step of the solution to the post I linked to. Now, does it not work for me because the *.hcd needs to go to a different location (as everything else is *.bin) in addition to this location? Could it be the naming of the hcd file? Is there some command to force load the *.hcd file into the kernel? do I need to remove some other piece of software? Can I load the driver I created using 'System Settings' > 'Software and Updates' > drivers tab?[image]

It seems that all that needs to be done is to somehow load the compiled hex file (hcd file) into the damn kernel. Any advice?

Other stuff I tried is:

1. Checked BIOS to make sure Bluetooth is enabled
2. Ran a bunch of commands I read about in a sea of Bluetooth heartbreak, but nothing worth mentioning here
3. Also, no wireless signals have been disabled:
   [image]
4. Kernel Version:
   `creator@PC-W530_Linux:~$ uname -a
   Linux PC-W530_Linux 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

If you need me to run any commands please let me know. Thanks!

********************************Edit #1**************************************

Some more commands:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb; lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 - First off.... Thank you for taking the time to respond!!!! I really appreciate it.  It just so happens that I figured out the problem - Your solution works perfect, unless you have 'blueman' installed! As soon as I got rid of blueman the bluetooth works. I will put the answer up in case someone else has this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue of firmware not working for a Broadcom Bluetooth you need to perform two steps (1) see: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu/632348#632348), and (2) uninstall 'Blueman'.

In my post I already worked through Pilot6's fix (step 1); but my bluetooth device was still not playing music (Was connected but still not playing music). Next I uninstalled blueman using software center:

[image]

At this point do a restart. After the restart there will only be one bluetooth logo (instead of two)
[image]

At this time pair the chosen device as usual. Now when you go to sound settings, you will see the Bluetooth device.

[image]

A massive thanks to Pilot6, first for posting a working solution, and second for responding when I asked for help. Thank You! Too bad the blueman software breaks the firmware used by the O/S, the blueman interface is really nice. Well problem fixed.... Hope this is of help to you.

Comment: If you really want Blueman, have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372071/bluetooth-device-paired-and-connected-no-sound?rq=1 maybe it will work for you...